# A web application framework built & implementation guideline?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, frameworks, web-frameworks

I want to built & implement a web application framework on .Net platform. The framework will be in three-tier organization architecture. I dont exactly know where to start. Is there any reference book, material, website,..etc. that anyone knows? Or is there anyone who tell me milestones of the process in outline?

I want my framework has these features:

1. Generic confirm and execute pages that works with web service request & responses.
2. Multi-language support.
3. Custom page life cycle instead of classic Asp.Net pages'.
4. Custom ui & server controls. (for example: a custom datagrid, dropdown,.. etc.)
5. Custom session & viewstate mechanism between pages. (via SetUIFromState, GetStateFromUI,.. procedures.)

That is all comes to my mind for now.

Comment: If you are looking for the latest framework, there's a good tutorial here: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirpas/archive/2013/08/06/writing-a-simple-implementation-of-dependency-injection-in-mvc-4-web-api-with-net-framework-4-5.aspx

Comment: why custom page life cycle ? and what is it all about, may be I am not getting this part of your question.

Comment: Thank you CalebC, but it seems that it is not that i am looking for, thank you anyway.

Comment: And Vinay, I will be doing a web application with this framework. I want to use only two procedures when a page loads: SetUIFromState and GetStateFromUI. All pages will be generic and there wont be any pageload, oninit implementations when pages are developed.